# Get ids of liked posts from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm using Buddypress with Buddypress like plugin and I want to get ids of all posts liked by a logged in user. There is a row in a database called `bp_liked_blogposts` with an array as a value. The row looks like this:

[image: row screenshot]

I tried to display this field `using get_user_meta` function and then implode the array with PHP to list of values. The result was "blogpost_liked","blogpost_liked"... but I need to get the number that goes after `i`:

I'm not PHP or Mysql expert so I need some help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually explode that data. The data is stored in JSON format. You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to automatically construct an array out of your data.